# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'xxx' was called on null (flutter widget)

Tags: flutter, dart

I know this question has been asked before but the previous questions and their answers have not helped me to figure out why I keep getting the exception:

> NoSuchMethodError: The method 'showProgress' was called on null.
> Receiver: null Tried calling showProgress()

I created a widget class MyProgress

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyProgress extends StatefulWidget {
  Color backgroundColor;
  Color color;
  Color containerColor;
  double borderRadius;
  String text;
  MyProgressState progressState;

  MyProgress(
    {
      this.backgroundColor = Colors.black54,
      this.color = Colors.white,
      this.containerColor = Colors.transparent,
      this.borderRadius = 10,
      this.text
    }
  );

  @override
  createState() => progressState = new MyProgressState(
      backgroundColor: this.backgroundColor,
      color: this.color,
      containerColor: this.containerColor,
      borderRadius: this.borderRadius,
      text: this.text);

  void hideProgress() {
    progressState.hideProgress();
  }

  void showProgress() {
    progressState.showProgress();
  }

  void showProgressWithText(String title) {
    progressState.showProgressWithText(title);
  }

  static Widget getMyProgress(String title) {
    return MyProgress(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
      color: Colors.black,
      containerColor: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: 5,
      text: title,
    );
  }
}

class MyProgressState extends State<MyProgress> {
  Color backgroundColor;
  Color color;
  Color containerColor;
  double borderRadius;
  String text;
  bool _opacity = false;

  MyProgressState(    
    {
      this.backgroundColor = Colors.black54,
      this.color = Colors.white,
      this.containerColor = Colors.transparent,
      this.borderRadius = 10,
      this.text
    }
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: !_opacity ? null : new Opacity(opacity: _opacity ? 1 : 0,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 300,
                height: 120,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: containerColor,
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.orange),
                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(blurRadius: 5)],
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                     new Radius.circular(borderRadius)
                  )
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new Center(
              child: _getCenterContent(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  Widget _getCenterContent() {
    if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
      return _getCircularProgress();
    }

    return Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          _getCircularProgress(),
          new Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: new TextStyle(color: color, fontSize: 18),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _getCircularProgress() {
    return CircularProgressIndicator(
        valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.deepOrange));
  }

  void hideProgress() {
    setState(() {
      _opacity = false;
    });
  }

  void showProgress() {
    setState(() {
      _opacity = true;
    });
  }

  void showProgressWithText(String title) {
    setState(() {
      _opacity = true;
      text = title;
    });
  }
}
```

I use my progress in my screen class: ItemsLoad

```
class ItemsLoad extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ItemsLoadState();
  }
}

class ItemsLoadState extends State<ItemsLoad> {
  var appBar = AppBar();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  List<Item> items;

  MyProgress progress = MyProgress.getMyProgress("Fetching Data ...");

  ItemsLoadState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (items == null) {
      items = List<Item>();
      progress.showProgress();
      requestData();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Items Loading"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - (appBar.preferredSize.height * 2)),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: items.length,
                      itemBuilder: bookListView,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - (appBar.preferredSize.height * 2)),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: progress,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

I would appreciate how to fix this exception since it occurs when the screen is loaded at first but an action button if tapped works well without any exception. Am still learning to use flutter and there could be some concepts I would missing here.

Comment: the value passed to showProgress() function seem to be null
try checking this value before calling showProgress() function

Comment: Would be useful the have the line number where the exception occurred (which should be in the error message)

Comment: @spkersten there is no line error in the exception.

Comment: Not in the exception, but there should be a stack tracé which points to the line that failed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are storing state in a widget. Widgets should be stateless, because new instances might be created when things are rebuild. When things are rebuild with a new instance of the widget and the type and key match those of the previous widget in the same place, then the element and the instance of the State subclass are reused. In that case `createState` isn’t invoked again.

In your case, when the widget gets rebuild for some reason, `progressState` will be empty.

Comment: Hey @spkersten I tried to work out with your answer but am sorry I don't understand anything as per your answer. I tried to make my widget stateless but i just got lost in it

Comment: You have to remove `MyProgressState progressState` from `MyProgress` (and it would be good to make all other fields final). A widget is an immutable blueprint, used to create something longer-lasting (an Element and often also a RenderObject). When things change while the app is running, new widgets might be created and the longer-lasting thing is told to update itself with the data from the new widget. So when that happens, the `progressState` field will be null. I have no idea what you’re trying to achieve with it, so i don’t know what alternative to offer.